# Changing CSS of dynamically created controls in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am creating a web application where I need to change the CSS class of one of the button that I have created dynamically using C# code.

The code that I am using is this

```
public void createbuttons()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.ID = "Button" + i.ToString();
        b.Text = i.ToString();
        PanelQuestionPallette.Controls.Add(b);
        b.CssClass = "buttongrey";
    }
}



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    createbuttons();
}



protected void ButtonChangeCss_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   foreach (Control c in PanelQuestionPallette.Controls)
   {
       if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button) && c.ID == ("Button" + Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])).ToString())
            {

                //c.Attributes.Add("class", "buttonpurpgreen");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change the CSS from "buttongrey" to "buttonpurpgreen".
Here the Session["QuestionCounter"] is a counter which is getting incremented.

Comment: In Page_Load, add `!Page.IsPostBack` control.

Comment: Thanks for your help @MehmetInce but I want to change CSS property here

Comment: You can try; `((Button)c).CssClass = "buttonpurpgreen";`

Comment: Great Skills! It worked.
Thanks for your help
Quote this as an answer, I will tick it as answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a template based approach like a repeater control, and instead rely on data binding for setting these values. You can then on post back set your bound properties to reflect the current css class.